# getting Not found page on every page at buttom React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am getting `not found` page on every page at bottom.
I have put `navbar` after `login & signup` so it is not visible on login & signup page.
I am getting not found  page in every page at buttom. I am not sure why it is comming.

```
 <Router>
                               
                                <Switch>
                                    <MyRoute
                                        restricted={userid}
                                        exactly
                                        path="/login"
                                        component={LoginSignupPage}
                                    />
                                    <MyNavBar>
                                        <PrivateRoute
                                            exactly
                                            path="/"
                                            component={HomePage}
                                        />
                                      
                                        <MyRoute
                                            restricted={false}
                                            exactly
                                            path="/user/:userId"
                                            component={UserProfilePage}
                                        />
                                        <MyRoute
                                            restricted={false}
                                            component={NotFoundPage}
                                        />
                                    </MyNavBar>
                                </Switch>
                              
                            </Router>
```

**MyRoute.tsx**

```
 <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            restricted ?
                <Redirect to="/" />
                : <Component {...props} />
        )} />
```

React router dom version
 `"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",`

Comment: which react-router-dom version you used ?

Comment: I am using  "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"  @ParthNavadiya

Comment: `react-router-dom` doesn't export a `Router`, instead, it exports a `BrowserRouter` so you need to import `{ BrowserRouter as Router }` from 'react-router-dom`.

Comment: that I have done already. I just faced problem  at `404 page` that coming on every page. @ParthNavadiya

Comment: Don't know why you facing same problem. for same you can check https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-golick-uedsr?file=/src/App.js and it's working for me. May be some issue in your other files.

Comment: yes, I fixed by wrapping each component with nav bar.

Comment: @ParthNavadiya RRD most certainly does export the lower level `Router` component. In fact, it re-exports *all* of the `react-router` exports.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed in this way

```
 <Router>
                               
                                <Switch>
                                    <MyRoute
                                        restricted={userid}
                                        exactly
                                        path="/login"
                                        component={LoginSignupPage}
                                    />
                                  
                                        <PrivateRoute
                                            exactly
                                            path="/"
                                            component={HomePage}
                                        />
                                      
                                        <MyRoute
                                            restricted={false}
                                            exactly
                                            path="/user/:userId"
                                            component={UserProfilePage}
                                        />
  <MyNavBar>
                                        <MyRoute
                                            restricted={false}
                                            component={NotFoundPage}
                                        />
                                    </MyNavBar>
                                </Switch>
                              
                            </Router>
```

```
  <MyNavBar>
<Route {...rest} render={props => (
            restricted ?
                <Redirect to="/" />
                : <Component {...props} />
        )} />
  </MyNavBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `Switch` component matches and renders the first `Route` or `Redirect` component. These are also the only valid children of the `Switch` component. You are rendering the `MyNavBar` as a child however, so this will ***always*** be rendered. The routes that are children of `MyNavBar` are now no longer wrapped in a `Switch` and are matched and rendered under the matching rules of your router.

As a reminder:

- `Router` components ***inclusively*** match and render routes. In other words, they render all matches.
- `Switch` component ***exclusively*** renders only the first match.

This means all the routes in `MyNavBar` are inclusively matched and since there is no `path` prop specified for `NotFoundPage` it will *always* match and be rendered.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <MyRoute
      restricted={userid}
      exactly
      path="/login"
      component={LoginSignupPage}
    />
    <MyNavBar>
      <PrivateRoute
        exactly
        path="/"
        component={HomePage}
      />
      <MyRoute
        restricted={false}
        exactly
        path="/user/:userId"
        component={UserProfilePage}
      />
      <MyRoute
        restricted={false}
        component={NotFoundPage}
      />
    </MyNavBar>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

You should wrap the nested/children routes of `MyNavBar` with another `Switch` to return to the exclusive route matching. And to be more *technically* correct the `MyNavBar` should probably also be rendered by a `Route` component. `exactly` also isn't a prop the `Route` components understand, perhaps you meant to use `exact` to exactly match a `path`. In the `Switch` component path order and specificity matter. You should order the paths from more specific to less specific. If done correctly you can nearly eliminate the need to *ever* need the `exact` prop.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <MyRoute
      restricted={userid}
      path="/login"
      component={LoginSignupPage}
    />
    <Route
      render={() => (
        <MyNavBar>
          <Switch>
            <MyRoute
              restricted={false}
              path="/user/:userId"
              component={UserProfilePage}
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path="/"
              component={HomePage}
            />
            <MyRoute
              restricted={false}
              component={NotFoundPage}
            />
          </Switch>
        </MyNavBar>
      )}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```